# How to handle exception in completableFuture in the for loop

Tags: exception, spring-transactions, spring-boot-actuator, completable-future

I am new to completableFuture, what I am trying to do is I have this logic below in spring boot project which I am trying to convert it to the parallel processing approach using completableFuture.

```
@Transaction
void serviceMethod{
    for(Object obj : objList) //objlist can have 10000 objects and its a multi level composite objects 
    {
        //Get corresponding entity obj from the database, if not found throw user exception 
        //Process i.e. change some fields 
        

    }
}
```

In the above logic sinnce the method is annotated with @Transaction I am not calling JPA save explicitly to save the entity.

Now, I am trying to do parallel processing with the above logic.

```
@Transaction
void serviceMethod{
    for(Object obj : objList) //objlist can have 10000 objects and its a multi level composite objects 
    {
    
        //Get corresponding entity obj from the database, if not found throw user exception 
        CompletableFuture<Optional<Obj>> optionalObjFuture = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync( () -> {//get the object from repository})
        
        
        CompletableFuture<Obj> objFuture = optionalObjFuture.thenApply( optionalObj -> {
                            if(obj.isPresent()){
                                return obj.get();
                            }
                            else{
                                throw user exception;
                            }
                        })
                        
        ////Process i.e. change some fields 

    }
}
```

Now the question is

1. what is the approach I have to follow to break the for loop when there is an exception?
2. How to handle transaction in this scenario. Is there any way to handle transaction without the need to call saveAll on the processed objects stored in datastructure?

Answer (score 0):

For (1), you could split those `10_000` calls into much smaller batches. For example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    int innerIterations = 5;
    ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(innerIterations);

    for(int i=0;i<10;++i) {

        List<CompletableFuture<String>> list = new ArrayList<>();
        int j = 0;
        for(;j<innerIterations;++j) {
            CompletableFuture<Optional<String>> cf = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> Optional.of("a"), service);


            CompletableFuture<String> cf2 = cf.thenApplyAsync(x -> {
                if(x.isPresent()) {
                    return x.get();
                } else {
                    throw new RuntimeException("test");
                }
            }, Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2));

            list.add(cf2);
        }

        i += j;

        CompletableFuture<Void> all5 = CompletableFuture.allOf(list.toArray(new CompletableFuture[0]));
        if(all5.isCompletedExceptionally()) {
            // log exception, whatever
            break;
        } else {
            List<String> set = list.stream().map(CompletableFuture::join).collect(Collectors.toList());
            System.out.println(set);
        }

    }

}
```

This does a couple of things:

- splits the initial `10` into two batches of `5`.
- call `CompletableFuture::allOf` on those 5 futures. Read the documentation to see that if at least one future fails from those `5`, then `all5` failed also.
- if `all5` did not fail (that is `all5.isCompletedExceptionally()` did not pass), call `CompletableFuture::join` to get all of the results. There will be no "joining" really, since the previous `allOff` already waited for them to be completed.

For the second question - you can't. You will need to create a transaction manually, but Spring makes it rather easy.

Comment: Thank you for guiding me. This would help me for sure.

Comment: @Vibha if this helped in any form, you could accept the answer.